# Cross-threading forms in C# with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, multithreading

I'm creating an application that uses .Net and Mono, it uses cross-threaded forms as I was having bad response from the child windows.

I created a test program with 2 forms: the first (form1) has a single button (button1) and the second (form2) is blank, code snippet below.

```
void openForm()
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread x = new Thread(openForm);
    x.IsBackground = true;
    x.Start();
}
```

This works fine in .Net, but with Mono, the first window will not gain focus when you click it (standard .ShowDialog() behaviour) rather than .Show() behaviour as .Net uses.

When I use .Show(), on .Net and Mono the window just flashes then disappears. If I put a 'MessageBox.Show()' after 'form2.Show()' it will stay open until you click OK.

Am I missing something in that code or does Mono just not support that? (I'm using Mono 2.8.1)

Thanks in advance, Adrian

EDIT: I realised I forgot 'x.IsBackground = true;' in the code above so child windows will close with the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Winforms controls, you shold "touch" the object always in main UI thread.

And at least - calling new Form.ShowDialog() in new thread does not make sense.

**EDIT:**
If you want easy work with Invoke/BeginInvoke you can use extension methods:

```
public static class ThreadingExtensions {
    public static void SyncWithUI(this Control ctl, Action action) {
        ctl.Invoke(action);
    }
}
// usage:
void DoSomething( Form2 frm ) {
    frm.SyncWithUI(()=>frm.Text = "Loading records ...");

    // some time-consuming method
    var records = GetDatabaseRecords();
    frm.SyncWithUI(()=> {
        foreach(var record in records) {
            frm.AddRecord(record);
        }
    });

    frm.SyncWithUI(()=>frm.Text = "Loading files ...");

    // some other time-consuming method
    var files = GetSomeFiles();
    frm.SyncWithUI(()=>{
        foreach(var file in files) {
            frm.AddFile(file);
        }
    });

    frm.SyncWithUI(()=>frm.Text = "Loading is complete.");
}
```

Comment: I'm not accessing any objects from a different thread to that that created them, I didn't think that calling .ShowDialog() made sense either but that's what is used in all of the sites I found while searching

Comment: You should create other Winforms object in UI thread too. But in your code, you creates and shows new form in paralel thread. It's not good idea, because in this situation there is much harder keep all calls in correct threads. The correct thread is the thread where was object created (where was constructor called).

Comment: I need the form to be run independently of everything else, so should I have it in the same thread but all the time-consuming functions in a separate thread? the reason I avoided that was because of all of the .Invokes it would require.

Comment: Yes, you should show form in the same (UI) thread and all other time consuming work should be done in paralel thread.

Comment: If you are not familiar with Invoke/BeginInvoke, you can use extension methods for better API. Look at my edit.

Comment: OK, that makes it much simpler, I was always checking if an Invoke was required and repeating a lot of code, I'll do it like that instead as it seems neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never the right thing to do in a Windows app to have more than one thread talk to one window or multiple windows which share the same message pump.

And it's rarely necessary to have more than one message pump.

The right way to do this is either to manually marshal everything back from your worker threads to your Window, using the 'Invoke' method, or use something like BackgroundWorker, which hides the details for you.

In summary:

- Don't block the UI thread for time-consuming computation or I/O
- Don't talk to the UI from more than one thread.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post, the only reason I have separate threads was for performance, I'd considered making everything else in separate threads instead of the forms but it would require a lot of rewriting of the code, I'll probably do it eventually but I'd like to get it working like this.  So does Mono just not support what like .Net does? or is there a way to do it?